# Tiered storage function not work in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

I performed the following steps:

1. Change 3 meta's config file: set auto_migrate_vnodes_duration = 60
2. Start the cluster by running run_cluster.sh.
3. Cnosdb-cli:

```
public ❯ ALTER NODE 1001 ATTRIBUTE COLD;
Query took 0.024 seconds.
public ❯ CREATE DATABASE db1 WITH VNODE_DURATION '1m' COOLING_DURATION '1m';
Query took 0.021 seconds.
```

4. run `curl -u 'root:' -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:8902/api/v1/write?db=db1' -d 'ma,ta=a fa=1'`

After step 4, I can find vnode in /tmp/cnosdb/2001/db/data/cnosdb.db1.
After waiting for a while, it should be able to see the vnode migrated to 1001, but the vnode is still at 2001.